# How to add x-coordinates on x axis in a bar plot using ggplot?

Tags: r

I am making a plot of the distribution of simulated streak lengths of the independent shooter. The x axis is length (0, 1, 2, 3, etc. each stands for a different situation) and y axis is count (how many times). Here is my simple code:

```
ggplot(data = sim_streak, aes(x = length)) + geom_bar()
```

The bar plot shows as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDdoo.png)

But the x-coordinates are only "0", "2", "4", "6", "8". How could I add more x-coordinates on x axis, like "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7","8"?

At beginning, I thought it was because my plots area in Rstudio was not big enough to accommodate all the x-coordinates. But it did not work even though I enlarge the size of the layout of the pane.

Then, I tried to search and tested whether scale_x_continuous () worked or not. Unfortunately I failed.

Look forward to your suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your x variable to a factor, then plotting. Use `+ xlab()` to change the x-axis title.

```r
data.frame(x=1:10,y=runif(10)) %>% ggplot(aes(factor(x),y)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + xlab('situation number')
```

[image: bar plot]

Comment: Thank you, kstew. Inspired by your suggestion on factor converting, I have updated the code and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

As Kstew pointed out, you probably want to make a vector with the right names for the groups you are plotting. But if you **need** to change them by hand you could use the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c("group 1", "group 2")

y <- c(10,15)

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = x, y = y), stat = "identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Group A", "Group B"))
```

I however do not recommend doing this as it is error prone. 
[GGplot barplot with hand drawn names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRhUf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code as

```
ggplot(data = sim_streak, aes(x = factor(length))) + geom_bar() + xlab('length')
```

[And the plot shows as:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8ZXE.png)
Without the "xlab('length')", the x-axis label will be "factor(length)". Thank you for your suggestions.